# How to request to another port with grunt server?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

`grunt server` run at `http://127.0.0.1:9000` port, and I want to make a request to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/api`.

If request with `/api`, it will become `http://127.0.0.1:9000/api`, which will return 404 because it's not exist.

If request with absolute url `http://127.0.0.1:8080/api` will get error:

`No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:9000' is therefore not allowed access.`

So, how can I make a request to another port in grunt server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finaly I solve this problem with [grunt-connect-proxy](https://github.com/drewzboto/grunt-connect-proxy), which provides a http proxy as middleware for the grunt-contrib-connect plugin.

Answer (score -2):

Based on tip from [here](https://gist.github.com/Vp3n/5340891), put this in your gruntfile.js

```
grunt.initConfig({
    connect: {
      livereload: {
        options: {
          port: 9000,
          hostname: 'localhost',
          middleware: function (connect) {
            return [
              function(req, res, next) {
                res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
                res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*');
                next();
              },
            ];
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });
```